# Webpage Reference using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to identify from where a visitor coming to my webpage.Is there anyways to getting that reference in a javascript file.eg: if my website is www.example.com.if user getting this site from google or bing search,then i need to identify that,user from google or bing respectivly.How can i get this in javascript(more priority) or in php.If anybody know help me please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the [**Referer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer) information.

In PHP, you can access it with **`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`**.

In Javascript, I suppose that this should give you that information : **`document.referrer`**.

Note : the referer is an information that's sent by the user's browser, which means :

- It can, or cannot, be sent

  - Which means your application can use it to provide some additionnal stuff,
  - But must work even if the Referer is not there.
- It can be forged

  - Which means you must not trust it for any important feature.
  - And you might want to filter/validate it

Comment: which is correct but,document.referrer method not working with my browser.i dont know why?I am using firefox.thanks.

Comment: I just gave it a try, with Firefox, and it worked properly ; are you sure there's a referer sent, in your case ?